# Prevent imports outside module except through index

Tags: typescript, import

Is there a simple solution (lint rule perhaps?) which can help enforce clean code imports through index files? I'd like to prevent importing code from "cousin" files, except if it is made available through an index file.

Ex:

```
- app
  + dogs
  | + index.ts  
  | + breeds
  | |  + retriever.ts
  | |  + schnauzer.ts
  | + activities
  |    + playing.ts
  |    + walking.ts
  + cats
    + index.ts
    + breeds
    |  + siamese.ts
    |  + persion.ts
    + activities
       + sleeping.ts
       + hunting.ts
```

Importing from the perspective of `cats/activities/hunting.ts`:

```
import { sleeping } from './sleeping'       // VALID - inside same folder
import { siamese } from '../breeds/siamese' // VALID - inside cats module
import { playing } from '../../dogs'        // VALID - importing from an index

import { retriever} from '../../dogs/activities/breeds' // INVALID - cousin file outside module possibly not exported from index
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use eslint's [`import/no-internal-modules` rule](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/no-internal-modules.md) and configure separate `.eslintrc` rules per "root" module.

In your `dogs` folder, create a new `.eslintrc` file with this contents:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "import/no-internal-modules": [ "error", {
      "allow": [ "app/dogs/**", "app/*" ],
    } ]
  }
}
```

This means any js/ts file within the dogs folder (or any sub folder of dogs) may import files from its own package *OR* any package like `/cats`

Do the same for your `cats` and any other "root" module.

Comment: i don't think this works as expected. for me, I can still import from other directories under app. also shouldn't this stop you importing 3rd party npm packages?

Answer (score 2):

The eslint [`no-restricted-imports`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports) rule can be used to provide custom rules for import patterns. This pattern prevents anything 2+ levels up and then 2+ levels down, which prevents cousin imports.

```json
"no-restricted-imports": [
  "warn",
  {
    "patterns": [
      {
        "group": ["**/../../[a-zA-Z]*/[a-zA-Z]*/**"],
        "message": "File not exposed from the module. Consider exporting it from an index"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: where is this created at the root or in the module?